# How can I remove these screws from shutters?

Tags: screws

I am trying to pull some wood shutters off vinyl siding. The screws are placed into what looks like a cylinder (I believe it is called an "anchor"), which itself looks attached to the siding. But when you get working on the screws, instead of coming out, they simply spin and make a popping noise every once in awhile. How can I get these shutters off?

Note: This is not simply one isolated screw; none of them will come out on any of the shutters. I have also put a crowbar behind the shutter to pull it from the wall so that the screw would "catch", but that didn't work either.

Comment: Pictures are always helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried just pulling the screw?  If it is a plug anchor it should just pull right out with moderate force. If it is a toggle-like anchor (where something expands behind the wood), try pulling the screw until it feels tight, then hold the anchor with a pair of pliars and try turning the screw.

Worst case just cut the screw off with a pair of tin snips, a rotary tool with a cut-off wheel, etc. Once the screw head is off you can probably just push the rest of the screw and anchor into the void behind the wall.

Answer (score 0):

First, try other screws first.  Sounds like some of them didn't "bite" and are just spinning.

Apply a slight pulling pressure to the shudder near the point of the screw connection as you're unscrewing it as well.

Comment: I have done both those things, but they didn't work!

Comment: Hmm.  Can you post some pics?